# Problem with definition of planar graphs.

Tags: planar-graphs

Is a graph with only vertices and no edges counted as a planar graph? 
And is a graph with only one edge also considered as a planar graph.

Comment: One edge... and no vertices?

Comment: You can draw a graph with no edges in the plane with no edges crossing, so yes, it's planar.

Comment: One edge 2 vertices.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the confusion.